# Datastore KeyFactory-generated ID and JPQL limitations?

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus, google-cloud-endpoints

I encountered a weird behaviour while working on my project (Google Cloud Endpoints + Datanucleus JPA).
I want to maintain the IDs of an unowned entity using the `KeyFactory.createKeyString(String kind, String name)` method, but I get a strange behaviour when executing a query over these IDs.

**Parent.java**

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Unowned
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Child child;

    // constructors, getters and setters
}
```

**Child.java**

```
@Entity
public class Child {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private String name;

    public Child() {}

    public Child(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = KeyFactory.createKeyString("Child", name);
        //this.id = id.substring(0, id.length() - 1);  // magic line!
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

**JPQL query**: `"select p from Parent p join p.child c where c.id = :childId"`

Now the problem is as follows:
* If the magic line is commented out, I always get an empty list out of my query.
* If the magic line is uncommented, everything works perfectly.

For info: the generated IDs are usually around 40 to 50 chars, and are HTML-safe (alphanumerics only). Here is an example of a generated ID using the KeyFactory method: `agR0ZXN0chALEgZBcnRpc3QiBERhbGkM`

Can anybody explain this weird behaviour?

**UPDATE**:
I even tried replacing the magic line with `id = id + "a";` or any other character, and this works as well. Which means it's definitely not a size limit issue.

Comment: why not debug your problem by looking in the LOG. It tells you of communication with Google's datastore and that is the where the problem is likely to be.

Comment: The log looks normal (just info messages from Datanucleus.Enhancer).  
Also, I am working on my local dev server.  
I'm not getting any errors or exceptions, I simply get an empty list without the magic line (when I should get results). It's probably something to do with the JPA implementation.

Comment: if you are debugging a problem its more normal to look at DEBUG level.; that tells you what is sent to/from the database. No idea what "normal" is that you refer to. The "JPA implementation" is Google's plugin https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/